# Convert json into matrix table? Javascript / HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

suppose I have a JSON object, in the example users can give a rating to themselves

```
[
    {
        "to": "jeff",
        "rating": 50,
        "from": "jeff"
    },
    {
        "to": "bob",
        "rating": 50,
        "from": "jeff"
    },
    {
        "to": "jeff",
        "rating": 75,
        "from": "bob"
    },
    {
        "to": "bob",
        "rating": 75,
        "from": "bob"
    }
]
```

I know how to display this in a simple grid panel like below

[image]

But this is a bit confusing, is there an easy way to convert this into a matrix table grid similar to the format below?

[image]

Just looking for a pure JS / jquery way of doing it, many thanks for any input!

Comment: I think you are looking to pivotable

Comment: It's a matrix table I think I need, just unsure how to parse the json into one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some hashes for the right row/col reference

```js
var data = [{ "to": "jeff", "rating": 50, "from": "jeff" }, { "to": "bob", "rating": 50, "from": "jeff" }, { "to": "jeff", "rating": 75, "from": "bob" }, { "to": "bob", "rating": 75, "from": "bob" }],
    result = [['to/from']];

data.forEach(function (row, col) {
    return function (a) {
        if (!(a.to in row)) {
            row[a.to] = result.push([a.to]) - 1;
        }
        if (!(a.from in col)) {
            col[a.from] = result[0].push(a.from) - 1;
        }
        result[row[a.to]][col[a.from]] = a.rating;
    };
}(Object.create(null), (Object.create(null))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```